# & is getting converted to &amp; in xml output . How to avoid that in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I am assigning some string value to an attribute of the node which contains & symbol. In the Xml output I am getting ampersand in place of & How can I avoid that?

Here is the code that I have written :

```
     XmlAttribute attr=doc.CreateAttribute("name");
     attr.Value ="me&mine";
     node.Attributes.Append(attr);
     itemnode.AppendChild(node);
     doc.Save(path);
```

I am getting output like

```
     <add name="me&amp;mine"/>
```

Comment: If you "avoid" that the result will not be valid XML. Any XML parser worthy of the name will do the reverse conversion when reading the XML, so there is absolutely no reason to do anything here.

Comment: That's right, with a single `&` you would get a not _well formed_ XML document, parsing it would give an error.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this a problem?

Comment: Use JSON, problem solved. :)

Answer (score 6):

That would be the correct output (in fact, it would be invalid as XML if the ampersand *wasn't* encoded)

Answer (score 2):

That's the correct behaviour! If your encoding didn't take place you end up with badly formed xml.

When you load the XML back into your application the `&amp;` will be converted back to a `&` character without you having to do anything about it.